# change shop URL in woo-commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Right now `www.mysite.com/shop` list all product.
I want to list other content in `shop` page (say only category) and in `www.mysite.com/shop-product` to show content what is shown right now in shop page.

I have tried changing Permalink in edit post page `www.mysite.com/shop-product` and it is showing all product as desired but problem is same content is also shown when i access url `www.mysite.com/shop`.

any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to change shop URL then follow the given steps below

1. Go to *Woocommerce* -> *Settings* -> *Products* tab -> *Display*
2. Under the *Shop & product pages* heading, select your custom *Shop page*
3. Save changes

It will work :)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

1. **WooCommerce Settings** click on the **Products Tab**
2. On the **Products Tab** check for the **Shop page** option
3. **Select the page** that you want to be the new shop page
4. **Save the settings**.